# Selenium Python: How can I disable JavaScript while using headless Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Using these options together doesn't work as expected:

```py
options.add_argument('--disable-javascript')
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

[When I disable JavaScript **without using headless mode**, it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iti4G.png)

[But when I try to disable JavaScript **with headless mode**, it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sDgB.png)

Comment: it is still NOT possible to disable JavaScript in Chrome when headless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now possible to disable JavaScript in headless Chrome if you use the new headless mode:

The new way (2023): `--headless=new` (Chrome 109 and above)

The previous way: `--headless=chrome` (Chrome 96 - Chrome 108)

(The old way: `--headless`)

There's more info on that here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

For the updated Chrome 109 info, see: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4

You can use the code below as options for completely disabling JavaScript while running headlessly:

```py
prefs = {}
prefs["webkit.webprefs.javascript_enabled"] = False
prefs["profile.content_settings.exceptions.javascript.*.setting"] = 2
prefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript"] = 2
prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript"] = 2

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument('--disable-javascript')
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```

Comment: I'm so sorry , it reminds me that "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I'm a noob , one day i have enough reputation , I will go back to vote for you. Really really thanks!

Comment: This options.add_argument('--headless=chrome') was key for me to work. I had options.headless = True

Comment: Starting with Chrome 109, use `--headless=new`. (They just changed it)